# Intuition for Azuma inequality proof

Tags: probability-theory, intuition

How could one come up with the proof of Azuma inequality? I'm looking for intuition for the proof.
I'm reading the proof provided here:
http://willperkins.org/6221/slides/azuma.pdf

I have a martingle $X_1,X_2...X_m$with small differences, why should I think of bounding $E[e^{a{X_m}}]$? Why not some other function? After making this steps I think I understand why we do the rest of the stuff, but this intial step...

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same question when I first saw this inequality. I'm going to show you my reasoning and then you can tell me what you think about it.

From the Markov inequality, for $X\geq 0$ and $f\geq0$ increasing, we know that
$$\mathbb{P}(X>t)\leq  \mathbb{P}(f(X)>f(t)) \leq f(t)^{-1}\mathbb{E}(f(X)). $$

Notice that for the above expression be helpful, we need information about $\mathbb{E}f(X)$ and it would be nice if $f(t)$ has some good properties and $f(t)^{-1}$ has good tail decay.

So, $f(x)=e^{tx}$ is a natural choice, because $e^{-tx}$ decays very fast in $t$; $f(x)$ is convex (this is a key point in the proof of Azuma/Hoeffding inequality ); and also because we often know what $\mathbb{E}(e^{tX})$ is, since this is the moment-generating function of $X$.

I think these are good  reasons for why these Azuma–Hoeffding type inequalities always make uses of $f(x)=e^{xt}$ as a function for finding bounds.